# not able to display in html top object from json in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I was able to get the value from the below json format from property but not the above data where I was not able to take the data like name,tags& updated-by.

```
        {
      "name" : "abc",
      "tags" : "def",
      "updated-by" : "ijk",
      "property" : {
        "description" : "abcd",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "sources" : {
        "input" : {
          "type" : "lmn",
          "properties" : {
            "key" : "opq"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Please find my ts code

```
              ngOnInit() {
            const routestream = this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap =>{
              this.id = paramMap.get('id');
            }
            );
            this.unsubscribe.push(routestream);
                /* initially loading data to display procedure and cost table */
                const empDetails = this.dataService.getDetails(this.id).subscribe(response => {
                  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<details>(response.property); 
                  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
                  this.isLoading = false;
                }, (error) => {
                  this.errorMessage = error;
                  this.isLoading = false;
                });
                this.unsubscribe.push(empDetails);
          }
```

While I am trying to access the top object like below in html

```
           <div class="row">
            <div class="rectangle-blue">
               {{element.name}}
                <label class="box-text">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="rectangle-blue">
                {{element.tags}}
                <label class="box-text">tags</label>                
            </div>
            <div class="rectangle-blue">
                {{element.updated-by}}
                <label class="box-text">Updated By</label>                
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am getting error not able to read the property.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: post your complete HTML

Comment: what is element here? show full .ts and .html file code

Comment: @Sajeetharan here I have updated the entire code

Comment: Where is element ? Can't find element in ts.

Comment: @Kahou actually i was trying to get the value using element

Comment: not sure how to access the top json value

Answer (score 0):

Watch the tutorial of [Get data from a server](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#get-data-from-a-server)

### Define an interface:

```
export interface RespData {
  name: string;
  tags: string;
  // ...
}
```

### Fetch response:

```
myResponse: RespData;

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getDetails(this.id).subscribe((response: RespData) => {
    this.myResponse = response;
  }
}
```

### html:

```
<div class="rectangle-blue">
    {{myResponse.name}}
    <label class="box-text">Name</label>
</div>
<div class="rectangle-blue">
    {{myResponse.tags}}
    <label class="box-text">tags</label>                
</div>
```